# Obtain text from select drop down list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, cucumber

I don't necessarily want the values from a select dropdown list, but I'm looking to create a regex step that will pull text (i.e. 'Select Country') for a cucumber step I have created

```
<option value>Select Country</option>  <----
<option value="1">Argentina</option>
```

Here's the cucumber step that I've written:

```
And the "follower[country_id]" field should contain "Select Country"
```

Any help or resources would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Capybara, this should give you the text of the selected item:

```
find('#follower[country_id]').value
```

http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Simple:value